Which nuget contains SecurityStampValidatorOptions
In a dotnet library project I need access to SecurityStampValidatorOptions.
That appears to be part of the "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" assembly, whose nuget package is deprecated.
So I tried referencing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore, but that also doesn't help. I get

The type or namespace name 'SecurityStampValidatorOptions' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

(It is definitely in that namespace though, and in my main ASP.NET Core project, it works.)
Where is that class defined?

The ASP.NET Core reference packages are imported into a project through the project's SDK attribute instead of specific NuGet Gallery PackageReference elements. Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref is "not meant to be used as a normal PackageReference" because the ASP.NET Core libraries don't get bundled with the app, they are expected to exist when run on a computer with the ASP.NET Core Runtime installed.
Project SDK
You can try changing your library project's .csproj file to use the ASP.NET Core SDK by appending .Web to the /Project/@Sdk attribute:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>

This will add a framework reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.App in your library project, which will include Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.dll, among many other assemblies.
Framework reference
Alternatively, you can manually add a framework reference to these libraries without changing the project SDK.
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <ItemGroup>
        <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>

For more information, see Use ASP.NET Core APIs in a class library.

Thanks Ben. I'm aware of the "App" metapackage but was hoping to reference something smaller. I use many classes from the framework, but they typically exist within Microsoft.AspNetCore... or Microsoft.Extensions... packages. I even use some of Identity that way. Are you saying that this particular class is only available via the metapackage?

For example, in the class library I do have access to many classes in the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.... namespace, just not the one I want. Weird.

I checked NuGet for all packages that contain the type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidatorOptions using ReSharper NuGet Browser. Besides the Ref and deprecated packages already mentioned above, there are four other packages that are very third-party, unpopular, and unmaintained, so I probably wouldn't use them with all the supply chain attacks in the news: Core.Identity, DotNetflixOAuth, GmodNET.Build.BundledRuntime, and myservice.

Thanks! That seems like a really useful tool.

It's very helpful if you already have ReSharper, but I wish there were a CLI or an Export button so I could copy all the results into a comment, or a web site to use it without ReSharper. In Java this is a first-class feature of the package repository websites, but it looks like JetBrains maintains their own private NuGet Gallery index for this purpose, and the official NuGet Gallery advanced search does not handle searching by type name.

NuGet and the official API pages have many deficiencies, but I find that https://source.dot.net makes up for some of them.

That's really helpful, I haven't seen that site before. Bookmarking.
